# Sort 2 tables at the same time via using LinQ

Tags: c#, linq

My example contains 2 tables `Book` and `Comment`.

`Book`:

```
Id           Name           UserId           DateTime

B1           Book1          User1            16/11/2016 11:15:00
B2           Book2          User1            16/11/2016 12:15:00
B3           Book3          User2            16/11/2016 10:15:00
```

`Comment`:

```
Id           BookId        UserId            DateTime

C1           B3            User1             16/11/2016 11:17:00
C2           B1            User1             16/11/2016 11:16:00
```

List of `Book` via specific user id:

```
string userid = "User1";

IEnumerable<Book> books = _context.Books.Where(x => x.UserId == userid);
```

List of `Comment`:

```
IEnumerable<Book> comments = _context.Comments.Where(x => x.UserId == userid);
```

In activity history (web page), I want to show all `books` and `comments` what I have collected via `userid`, one by one. But, how can I sort 2 objects again via `.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTime)`?

My goal:

`User1` just postes a new book to the store:

```
B2           Book2          User1            16/11/2016 12:15:00
```

Before that, he posted a comment to his own thread:

```
C1           B1            User1             16/11/2016 11:17:00
```

Earlier, he posted a comment in another thread (`UserId == "User2"`):

```
C2           B3            User1             16/11/2016 11:16:00
```

Older, he posted a new book to the store:

```
B1           Book1          User1            16/11/2016 11:15:00
```

I can classify them via `DateTime` column (on paper):

```
16/11/2016 12:15:00
16/11/2016 11:17:00
16/11/2016 11:16:00
16/11/2016 11:15:00
```

How can I sort it?

**UPDATE:**

I just found a solution but LinQ. I want a solution using LinQ with same result (for shorter):

```
namespace MP
{
    public class Book
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    }

    public class Comment
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string BookId { get; set; }

        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public string Content { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public object Object { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                string userid = "User1";

                var books = new List<Book>();
                books.Add(new Book { Id = "B1", Name = "Book1", UserId = "User1", DateTime = new DateTime(2016, 11, 16, 11, 15, 00) });
                books.Add(new Book { Id = "B2", Name = "Book2", UserId = "User1", DateTime = new DateTime(2016, 11, 16, 12, 15, 00) });
                books.Add(new Book { Id = "B3", Name = "Book3", UserId = "User2", DateTime = new DateTime(2016, 11, 16, 10, 15, 00) });

                var comments = new List<Comment>();
                comments.Add(new Comment { Id = "c1", BookId = "B3", UserId = "User1", Content = "cmt1", DateTime = new DateTime(2016, 11, 16, 11, 17, 00) });
                comments.Add(new Comment { Id = "c2", BookId = "B1", UserId = "User1", Content = "cmt2", DateTime = new DateTime(2016, 11, 16, 11, 16, 00) });

                var result = new List<Result>();
                books.ForEach(x => 
                {
                    if (x.UserId == userid)
                    {
                        result.Add(new Result { Object = x, DateTime = x.DateTime });
                    }                    
                });

                comments.ForEach(x =>
                {
                    if (x.UserId == userid)
                    {
                        result.Add(new Result { Object = x, DateTime = x.DateTime });
                    }
                });

                result = result.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTime).ToList();

                foreach (var item in result)
                {
                    Type type = item.Object.GetType();

                    if (type == typeof(MP.Book))
                    {
                        var book = (Book)item.Object;

                        Console.WriteLine($"Book: Id: {book.Id} - Name: {book.Name} - DateTime: {book.DateTime}");
                    }

                    if (type == typeof(MP.Comment))
                    {
                        var cmt = (Comment)item.Object;

                        Console.WriteLine($"Comment: Id: {cmt.Id} - Content: {cmt.Content} - DateTime: {cmt.DateTime}");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: 1]

Comment: Exatly as you said .OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTime)

Comment: @Haksu Also, I want to compare `DateTime` in `Book` table with `DateTime` in `Comment` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's solution that should work for you.  Basically I took your idea of objectifying the data and creating a linq query that creates a list of objects from each list and sorts them according to the DateTime.  By overriding the ToString() method printing the contents of the list becomes very simple:

```
public class Book
{
    public const string className = "Book";
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Book:    Id: {Id.PadRight(7)} - Name: {Name.PadRight(14)} - DateTime: {DateTime}";
    }

}

public class Comment
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string BookId { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public string Content { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Comment: Id: {Id.PadRight(7)} - Content: {Content.PadRight(11)} - DateTime: {DateTime}";
    }

}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            string userid = "User1";

            var books = new List<Book>();
            books.Add(new Book { Id = "B1", Name = "Book1", UserId = "User1", DateTime = new DateTime(2016, 11, 16, 11, 15, 00) });
            books.Add(new Book { Id = "B2", Name = "Book2", UserId = "User1", DateTime = new DateTime(2016, 11, 16, 12, 15, 00) });
            books.Add(new Book { Id = "B3", Name = "Book3", UserId = "User2", DateTime = new DateTime(2016, 11, 16, 10, 15, 00) });

            var comments = new List<Comment>();
            comments.Add(new Comment { Id = "c1", BookId = "B3", UserId = "User1", Content = "cmt1", DateTime = new DateTime(2016, 11, 16, 11, 17, 00) });
            comments.Add(new Comment { Id = "c2", BookId = "B1", UserId = "User1", Content = "cmt2", DateTime = new DateTime(2016, 11, 16, 11, 16, 00) });
            var test = (from b in books
                        where b.UserId == userid
                        select (object)b).Concat
                        (from c in comments
                        where c.UserId == userid
                        select (object)c).OrderBy(x => x.GetType() == typeof(Book)?((Book)x).DateTime:((Comment)x).DateTime);
            foreach(var o in test)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(o);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Did some more thinking, using generic objects always makes me uneasy, and came up with a better solution.  by using a base class with the common properties and the book and comment classes deriving from that, the list you make can contain either book or comment and it can be filtered and sorted by any of the base class properties:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
public class Book:Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Book:    Id: {Id.PadRight(7)} - Name: {Name.PadRight(14)} - DateTime: {DateTime}";
    }

}

public class Comment:Item
{
    public string BookId { get; set; }

    public string Content { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Comment: Id: {Id.PadRight(7)} - Content: {Content.PadRight(11)} - DateTime: {DateTime}";
    }

}
```

Creating the filtered and sorted list becomes much simpler:

```
string userid = "User1";

var items = new List<Item>();
items.Add(new Book { Id = "B1", Name = "Book1", UserId = "User1", DateTime = new DateTime(2016, 11, 16, 11, 15, 00) });
items.Add(new Book { Id = "B2", Name = "Book2", UserId = "User1", DateTime = new DateTime(2016, 11, 16, 12, 15, 00) });
items.Add(new Book { Id = "B3", Name = "Book3", UserId = "User2", DateTime = new DateTime(2016, 11, 16, 10, 15, 00) });
items.Add(new Comment { Id = "c1", BookId = "B3", UserId = "User1", Content = "cmt1", DateTime = new DateTime(2016, 11, 16, 11, 17, 00) });
items.Add(new Comment { Id = "c2", BookId = "B1", UserId = "User1", Content = "cmt2", DateTime = new DateTime(2016, 11, 16, 11, 16, 00) });
var test = (from b in items
            where b.UserId == userid
            orderby b.DateTime
            select b);
foreach (var o in test)
{
    Console.WriteLine(o);
}
```

Comment: @TânNguyễn - I couldn't stop thinking about this and came up with a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this one:

```
 var vm = from b in Book
          join c in Comment on b.Id equals c.BookId into d
          where b.UserId == userid 
          orderby b.DateTime
          select new {
                      OrderedDate = from item in d
                                    orderby item.DateTime
                                    select item
                     }
```

or another approach by UNION it

```
var vm = (from a in book
         where a.UserId == userid
         select new { a.DateTime })
         .Union
         (from b in Comment
         where (x=> x.Book.Any(y=>y.UserId == userid))
         select new { b.DateTime })
         .Select(c => new { c.DateTime }).OrderBy(d => d.DateTime);
```

Comment: A simple join would not work. There may be books with no comments.

Comment: Error message: `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool' because it is not a delegate type` in `where (x => x.Book.Any(y => y.UserId == userid)` please!

Comment: hey sorry a bit crowded here. Hi I though you need comments where the comment.bookId.userid = userid but not. in that case, could you please try to change  `where (x=> x.Book.Any(y=>y.UserId == userid))` to `where (x=> x.UserId == userid))` ?? 
if still didn't work, may be I will try to play with it further

regards

Comment: @RizkiDPrast I will try again. I just update question with non-linq solution.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you would like to display the records of two tables with different columns in a single grid.

**Which columns are to be displayed?**

Lets say they are ID, TYPE (either book entry or comment entry) and DT (DateTime).

```
var result = (from b in _context.Books
              where b.UserId = userid
              select new {b.Id Id, "BOOK" Type, b.DateTime DT})
            .Union(
              (from c in _context.Comments
               where c.UserId = userid
               select new {c.Id Id, "COMMENT" Type, c.DateTime DT})
            ).OrderByDescending(x => x.DT);
```

Comment: You're right. I'm trying again with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

this is how i did,.

```
public class BookAndComment
        {
            public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
            public Book Book { get; set; }
            public Comment Comment { get; set; }
        }
```

and query

```
var orderedBooksAndComments = = books.Where(book => book.UserId == userId).Select(book =>
            new BookAndComment
            {
                DateTime = book.DateTime,
                Book = book
            }).Union(comments.Where(comment => comment.UserId == userId).Select(comment =>
                new BookAndComment
                {
                    DateTime = comment.DateTime,
                    Comment = comment
                }
            )).OrderByDescending(bookAndComment => bookAndComment.DateTime).ToList();
```

than

```
foreach (var item in orderedBooksAndComments)
{ 
if(item.Book!=null)
{
// Do something

}else
{
var comment = item.Comment;
// comment should not be null here. 
// Do something.
}
}
```

Comment: You are doing same to my iead. Perfect. But the problem with this way, you cannot show the ouput because `what's first?`. Something like: `foreach (var item in orderedBooksAndComments){    /* item.Book first or item.Comment first? */     }`

Comment: As we're getting Book or Comment when one is null other should not .